# Numeric keypad not working in WebBrowser control

Tags: winapi, webbrowser-control, atl

We have an ATL hosted WebBrowser control that is a child of a parent window in a different process.

Some users are not able to use the numeric keypad to type numbers in the text boxes in the WebBrowser control.

This has been seen on Windows 7 and Windows 10, and the problem does not appear to be related to the "Mouse Keys" accessibility option.

The numeric keypad works fine in other apps (IE and Notepad) on the same system, it only fails in our hosted WebBrowser control.

We have not been able to reproduce this problem, nor isolate anything in common with the systems where the problem is being encountered.  Can anyone explain what would cause the numeric keypad to fail only in the WebBrowser control?

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: Yes, it's "legal".  Challenging, but legal.

Comment: If either the ATL hosting code, or the cross-thread parent process is not under your control, it stops being legal. This question cannot be answered without a [mcve]. I know, that, too, is a challenge in itself.

Comment: But of course this question could be answered, all it would take is someone who has experienced similar behavior with the WebBrowser control who was able to reproduce the problem and find the answer.  The fact that we have a cross-process parent-child relationship may not be relevant.  I realize this may be considered a wild cast, but it's a specific question and you never know if someone has had a similar experience.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this problem is due to a utility called WebRoot SecureAnywhere Identity Shield  It was difficult to find because the problem is at the driver level, not User space.

They say they are working on a fix for this problem, but here is a workaround:

Run this program:

http://download.webroot.com/IDShieldNumLock.exe

If the tool is run without arguments, it will modify the registry and prompt if ID Shield now has control of Num-Lock (Enabled) or if ID Shield no longer has control (Disabled). It will then ask for a reboot to complete the process.

If the tool is run with an argument it will be run silently (for example: though Agent Command – Advanced – Download and run a file). Pass it one of the following arguments:

-disable turns OFF ID Shield’s control of Num-Lock (meaning it is now Disabled). The following are also valid arguments (/off, -off, /disable).

-enable turns ON ID Shield’s control of Num-Lock (meaning it is now Enabled). The following are also valid arguments (/on, -on, -enable).

If the tool is run with two or more arguments nothing will happen.

Note: The registry key that this affects is HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ikbevent “DWORD”:Type 0x01 with this key in place ID Shield’s control of Num-Lock is disabled and with it removed it is enabled.

This is also documented in the blog for our product where we were encountering the problem, but it will happen to any product that hosts the WebBrowser control:  https://www.ietab.net/blog/number-keypad-numlock-not-working-in-ie-tab/